# Is it possible to change the color of systemd (?) [FAILURE] [OK] or [SUCCESS] etc. in boot sequence?

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, boot

My problem is, that any script / command in /etc/init.d seems to be overridden by something else or disregarded.
So I guess that this must be something to be configured in the kernel.

For example using /etc/init.d/*some_script* (This content is about what I want):

```sh
# Column number to place the status message
RES_COL=60
# Command to move out to the configured column number
MOVE_TO_COL="echo -en \\033[${RES_COL}G"
# Command to set the color to SUCCESS (Green)
SETCOLOR_SUCCESS="echo -en \\033[1;36m"
# Command to set the color to FAILED (Red)
SETCOLOR_FAILURE="echo -en \\033[1;31m"
# Command to set the color back to normal
SETCOLOR_NORMAL="echo -en \\033[0;39m"

# Function to print the SUCCESS status
echo_success() {
    $MOVE_TO_COL
    echo -n "["
    $SETCOLOR_SUCCESS
    echo -n $" OK "
    $SETCOLOR_NORMAL
    echo -n "]"
    echo -ne "\r"
    return 0
}

# Function to print the FAILED status message
echo_failure() {
    $MOVE_TO_COL
    echo -n "["
    $SETCOLOR_FAILURE
    echo -n $"FAILED"
    $SETCOLOR_NORMAL
    echo -n "]"
    echo -ne "\r"
    return 1
}
```

I've been grepping around inside the kernel- and other sources and inside the system but found nothing about that.

/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c seems to be some global config for the VT. That's not what I need.

I would be happy to receive a few tips.

Greetings
Jens

Comment: Do you want to change the color of messages or add a script to init.d? `init.d` is ignored with systemd and `init.d` is _not_ a file, it's a directory? Does your system actually uses systemd or does it use openrc or sysvinit, upstart, initng, cinit, ruinit,... ? You tagged `linux-kernel` - why? How is the color of messages by your _user space_ system manager related to linux kernel?

Comment: The `echo` command may be a shell built-in. Check the docs for the shell running the script, or run the GNU echo binary explicitly as `/bin/echo`. Note that `-e` is non-POSIX. You might be better off using the `printf` command.

Comment: I just want to change the Color of the Status messages on boot. [OK] and [FAILURE]. The above script is just a try. I remember that making changes to this was possible some 15 years ago. I think it was in /init.d/funktions then. It was even possible to change the designation of the messages itself. Like [BLABLA] or so.

Answer (score 0):

This OS uses systemd.

I just started my old computer with Mandriva 2009 and coloring worked out of the box. There is a file 'etc/sysconfig/init' in which I can set the color but here on Magaia 7.1 there is no such file. I only have /etc/init.d/functions which says:

"This file contains functions to be used by most or all shell scripts in the /etc/init.d directory."

There is a block in it showing the color configuration:

```sh
# Read in our configuration
if [ -z "${BOOTUP:-}" ]; then
    if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/init ]; then
        . /etc/sysconfig/init
    else
        # verbose ->> very (very!) old bootup look (prior to RHL-6.0?)
        # color ->> default bootup look
        # other ->> default bootup look without ANSI colors or positioning
        BOOTUP=color
        # Column to start "[  OK  ]" label in:
        RES_COL=60
        # terminal sequence to move to that column:
        MOVE_TO_COL="echo -en \\033[${RES_COL}G"
        # Terminal sequence to set color to a 'success' (bright green):
        SETCOLOR_SUCCESS="echo -en \\033[1;36m"
        # Terminal sequence to set color to a 'failure' (bright red):
        SETCOLOR_FAILURE="echo -en \\033[1;31m"
        # Terminal sequence to set color to a 'warning' (bright yellow):
        SETCOLOR_WARNING="echo -en \\033[1;33m"
        # Terminal sequence to reset to the default color:
        SETCOLOR_NORMAL="echo -en \\033[0;39m"

        # Verbosity of logging:
        LOGLEVEL=1
    fi
    if [ "$CONSOLETYPE" = "serial" ]; then
        BOOTUP=serial
        MOVE_TO_COL=
        SETCOLOR_SUCCESS=
        SETCOLOR_FAILURE=
        SETCOLOR_WARNING=
        SETCOLOR_NORMAL=
    fi
```

But any changes do have no effect.

I tagged it linux-kernel because my guess was that this could be overriden by some kernel option or patch or config or someting like that.